# CI Build using Circleci or any other build tool with multiple modules in a parent folder

Tags: continuous-integration, maven-surefire-plugin, circleci

Is it possible to configure `circleci` if all my maven `project/modules` are placed inside a parent folder? Please provide examples or a sample `yml`.

```
> ProjectFolder  --.git  -- ModuleA
>     ----java
>     ----resources
>     ----pom  -- ModuleB
>     ----java
>     ----resources
>     ----pom  --ReadMe.
```